# save data format Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to save an output of matlab in ascii. It works but the problem is that the format is:

```
4.8143374e+07   1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00  
1.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00 4.0000000e+00
```

but I need 6 digits precision and round brackets like

```
(4.8143374e+07   1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00)  
(1.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00 4.0000000e+00)
```

Do you know how how I can do that? Thank you

best regards
L.Metelli

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use [`fprintf()`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) to write to a file and give it the following format specifier:

```
% After opening your file like this:  fid = fopen('myfile.asc', 'wt');
fprintf(fid, '(%0.6e %0.6e %0.6e)\n', data(1), data(2), data(3));
```

If you leave out the `fid` in the call to `fprintf()`, the results will be displayed in the command window.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `sprintf` function you can print data into formatted strings:

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html

Out of my head something like

```
str = sprintf("(%f.6 %f.6 %f.6)", data(0), data(1), data(2))
```

might work.

Comment: I think you need `.6`